# matching error in ORB with opencv 3

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.0, orb, flann

currently i am working on opevcv with python but when i use

```
    kp1 = orb.detect(img1,None)
    kp2 = orb.detect(img2,None)
    kp1, des1 = orb.compute(img1, kp1)
    kp2, des2 = orb.compute(img2, kp2)
    matches = matcher.match(des1, des2)
```

i get the error that matcher is not defined

```
    matches = matcher.match(des1, des2)
    NameError: name 'matcher' is not defined
```

, i am using opencv 3.0.0 with python 2.7, can anyone tell me why i am getting this error ??
can we use matcher or not with python ??

Comment: Have you created the [matcher object](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html) first?. Something like `matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)`

Comment: no, actually i am newbie in this field so i don't know whats the proper syntax of creating matcher object

Comment: Check the tutorial I posted in the link above

Comment: after creating the matcher object now i got a new error
 img12 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches,None,flag=2)
TypeError: 'flag' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: the tutorial suggests using `flags`, with the "s"! `cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:10], flags=2)`

Comment: thanks Miki, its done now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the `matcher` object first. A complete example can be found on [OpenCV tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('box.png',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('box_in_scene.png',0) # trainImage

# Initiate ORB detector
orb = cv2.ORB()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with ORB
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

# create BFMatcher object
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

# Match descriptors.
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)

# Sort them in the order of their distance.
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

# Draw first 10 matches.
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:10], flags=2)

plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

In the above code instead of `orb = cv2.ORB()`

```
use orb = cv2.ORB_create()
```

this resolves version compatibility issues:

> TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'Feature2D' or its
>   derivative)